# jQuery UI Datepicker error

Tags: wp-admin, jquery-ui, datepicker

Somehow, the default jQuery UI Datepicker (loaded by `domain/wp-includes/script-loader.php` on line 214 in version 4.7 is giving javascript errors in the console. This is the line that loads in the file:

```
$scripts->add( 'jquery-ui-datepicker', "/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/datepicker$dev_suffix.js", array('jquery-ui-core'), '1.11.4', 1 );
```

And here is the error:

```
edit.php:81 GET http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-nl.js?ver=4.7
```

It returns with an 404. How do I fix this error?

I have searched within the `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` files, but I just can't figure out why this error is present.

---

IMPORTANT:
I don't want to change any wp-admin code. Preferably, I want to use hooks via my custom plugin (or the theme's `functions.php` file)

Answer (score 1):

The script itself is no longer on the [**google hosted link**](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-nl.js). You should try updating to Wordpress v4.7.1 or reporting the bug if it still persists after that

[image: 404 error]

Comment: Is there no workaround? Because that's what I'm looking for

Comment: You could always enqueue your own local version of the script.

Comment: Tried that already. Removing the 'jquery-ui-datepicker' line solved the issue, but dequeue'ing or deregistering the  scripts did not solve the issue, even when I changed the priority